# How to call a method in a .NET Core assembly from .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have two assemblies:

1. The parent assembly is compiled against .NET Framework.
2. The child assembly is compiled against .NET Core.

**I want to call a method in the child assembly, and retrieve its return object**.  The constructor doesn't take any parameters. The method does not take any parameters, and returns a `Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel`

Things I've tried so far:

1. Creating a separate appdomain, and calling `domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
   ApplicationBase = path
   PrivateBinPath = path
};
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Child", null, setup);
AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);
object instance = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName.FullName, className);
```

2. Creating a class that extends `MarshalByRefObject`, and using that to load the assembly, call the function, and marshal the return type:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Child");
BinaryMarshal marshal = (BinaryMarshal) domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(BinaryMarshal).Assembly.FullName, typeof(BinaryMarshal).FullName);
IEdmModel model = marshal.LoadEdmModel(path, className, functionName);

//BinaryMarshal.cs:
internal class BinaryMarshal : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public IEdmModel LoadEdmModel(string binary, string className, string functionName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(binary);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className);  //returns null because of exception listed below
     }
}
```

In both cases, the code doesn't work because of the following exception (obtained from `Fuslogvw.exe`):

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/29/2019 @ 10:34:48 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\develop\parent\out\debug-amd64\Parent.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/develop/parent/out/debug-amd64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Parent.exe
Calling assembly : Child, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\develop\parent\out\debug-amd64\Parent.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/parent/out/debug-amd64//System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/parent/out/debug-amd64//System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/parent/out/debug-amd64//System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/parent/out/debug-amd64//System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/child/out/debug-amd64/netcoreapp2.0/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/child/out/debug-amd64/netcoreapp2.0/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/child/out/debug-amd64/netcoreapp2.0/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/develop/child/out/debug-amd64/netcoreapp2.0/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

From what I can tell, it's trying to load System.Runtime, which fails because parent app already has a different version of System.Runtime loaded.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core and .NET Framework are different runtimes. Try to use .NET Standard for common library and you will be able to use it from both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718943/calling-a-net-framework-4-or-mono-assembly-from-a-net-core-application

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: you can't call directly the .NET Core assembly from .NET Framework and vice versa. The .NET Core is not compatible with .NET Framework.

You can call the compatible assembly of .NET Core from .NET Framework assembly, as long as the assembly is targeted to use .NET Standard, preferably at least NET Standard 2.0 to provide compatibility with .NET Core 2.1 and 2.2 runtime.

See also the official doc of .NET Standard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: When you say "as long as the assembly is targeted to use .NET Standard", are you talking about the child or the parent assembly?

Comment: @NathanMerrill yes.

Comment: What does "Yes" mean?  Both assemblies have to be targeted to .NET Standard?

Comment: You should use .NET Standard as the main target of the assembly if you want your assembly to be compatible for both .NET Core and .NET Framework.